# Bounded Radon-Nikodym derivative of a measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, optimal-transport, radon-nikodym

Let $Y\subset\mathbb R^d$ and $X\subset\mathbb R$. Let $\mu\in\mathcal P(Y)$ be absolutely continuous with a density still denoted $\mu$ which is bounded with compact support (so $\mu(E)\leq\|\mu\|_{\infty}\mathcal L(E)$, where $\mathcal L$ is the Lebesgue measure). Let $\pi:Y\longrightarrow X$ be a Borel measurable function, which is continuous. Let $\nu\in\mathcal P(X)$ be the push-forward measure $\nu=\pi\#\mu$, which is absolutely continuous.

**My question is**: what are the conditions on $\pi$ (and on the measure $\mu$ if necessary) to have that the measure $\nu$ has a bounded (that is $L^{\infty}$) density? In other words, denoting by $\nu$ such a density, I want to write
$$
\nu(E)\leq\|\nu\|_{\infty}\mathcal L(E).
$$

A priori, I have that the density $\nu$ is only $L^1$.

Some  help? Thank you

Comment: If the $\pi$ has a bounded Jacobian then this is true.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was so, applying the change-of-variables theorem. But I cannot formalize it..

Comment: $\nu (E)=\int_{\pi^{-1}(E)} \mu (x)dx=\int_E \mu (x) J(\pi) (x) dx$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is it enough to assume that $\pi$ is Lipschitz continuous, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. The subset $X$ is in $\mathbb R$ not in $\mathbb R^d$. I think that the change-of-variables formula does not hold..